# Meteor.autorun vs Tracker.autorun?

Tags: meteor, meteor-tracker

What is the difference between `Meteor.autorun` and `Tracker.autorun`?

- are they just aliases?
- is one deprecated?
- is there any instance where one is preferable to the other?

I'm well aware of the difference in using `this.autorun` in template lifecycle callbacks, but have seen these two used interchangeably and just want to be sure I haven't missed a trick.

Comment: I'm guessing that Tracker.autorun is the official reference since Meteor.autorun is not even mentioned in the official documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full).

Comment: this is my assumption as well.....but assumptions make an ass out well... you know the rest.  Any reference to what the deal is officially would be great, I know at some stage there was `deps.autorun` which i believe is now deprecated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, it can easily be found out with the [identity operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity).

This will be `false` because it is not the same function:

```js
(function() {} === function() {})
```

Let's try with the two `autorun` :

```js
(Meteor.autorun === Tracker.autorun)
```

This returns `true`. So yes it's only a pure alias.
However, only [`Tracker.autorun` is documented](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun). I suspect some kind of old API left for compatibility...
Let's check some [Meteor code on GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/tracker/deprecated.js#L7)!

> File : `deprecated.js`
>
> ```js
> Meteor.autorun = Tracker.autorun;
> ```

This is in `deprecated.js`, it says some things about `//Deprecated functions` and some backward compatibility with Meteor *0.5.4*. It seems pretty clear which one you should use.
You can find some other old timers in there, such as `Deps`...

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `Meteor.autorun();` in the console, it throws the following error `Uncaught Error: Tracker.autorun requires a function argument` like you were trying to run `Tracker.autorun();`